# no rviz interface in Ubuntu 11.04 (natty)

Tags: rviz, ubuntu-natty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have exactly the same problem as described in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/946/no-rviz-interface), i.e. the rviz interface does not show up if I start roscore and "rosrun rviz rviz".

I have installed the latest ros-diamondback-* packages from the official repository (version 1.4.1-s1308330112~natty). I tried several different window managers including GNOME, Unity, and KDE Plasma. I tried four different computers with Natty, and the most disturbing part is that it works on exactly one machine (with KDE), but for no apparent reason; it is the same hardware (HP Z800 workstation).

I have successfully run Gazebo with Ogre and glxgears, so there is no obvious problem with my 3D acceleration (NVIDIA). There are no helpful error messages in the logs. There are a few warnings and errors, but they show up on the working machine as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10506/no-rviz-interface-in-ubuntu-11.04-(natty)/) by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1951 on 2011-07-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-09**:
The error may not be useful to you but please post it anyway.  Also what's the output of 'dpkg -l ros-diamondback-visualization'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem turned out to be the environment variable GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS. I have set this variable in my .bashrc to circumvent problems with Eclipse (see http://blogs.gurulabs.com/dax/2009/10/what-gdk-native.html for a more in-depth explanation). Without this variable, the interface shows up just fine.

However, a colleague of mine has set the same variable and it causes no problems for him. He uses Ubuntu Lucid, though.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1